# Searching within a big document

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I am searching within this (http://norvig.com/big.txt) file. and search results are not returning.

Searching for "the" "and" terms. And I m not getting back anything.

Here is the query :

```
var res = client.Search<Post>(f => f.Query(q => q.Term(z => z.Content, "the")));
```

When I browse through the index, i can view the document, but search is not working.

What would be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't specified an analyzer when indexing, the [standard](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html)-analyzer is used. It removes [stopwords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) such as `and`, `in`, `the` and so on.

Comment: is search term case sensitive?